# Update value to database with many to many relations Laravel

Tags: php, database, synchronization, many-to-many, laravel-5.3

I want to update value data from radio button to database table `product_categories` but I'm confused. Because my data is belongs to many.

Here my belongs to many function in Product Model

```html
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'products_categories','product_id','category_id')
            ->withPivot('id')
            ->orderBy('category_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Here my radio button structure in view

```html
{!! Form::model($product, ['route' => ['products.update', $product->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}
<div class="dropdown dropdown-full-width dropdown-category">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="name">
              <span id="category-select">Choose Category</span>
          </span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By {{ $category[1] }}</strong></li>
      @foreach($category1 as $occasions)
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['occasions']" class="category-radio" value="{{ $occasions->id }}"> {{ $occasions->name }}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By {{ $category[2] }}</strong></li>
      @foreach($category2 as $types)
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['types']" class="category-radio" value="{{ $types->id }}"> {{ $types->name }}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By {{ $category[3] }}</strong></li>
      @foreach($category3 as $flowers)
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['flowers']" class="category-radio" value="{{ $flowers->id }}"> {{ $flowers->name }}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and here my update function in controller

```html
public function update($id, UpdateProductRequest $request)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        $categories = Product::with('categories')->where('id','=', $product->id)->get();
        $idcategories = $categories[0]->categories;
        
        if (empty($product)) {
            Flash::error('Product not found');

            return redirect(route('products.index'));
        }

      //place update code for radio button here//

        Flash::success('Product updated successfully.');

        return redirect(route('products.index'));
    }
```

I'm very confused with many to many relation with sync.

### Update

Here my table structure in `product_categories`

[image]